# JSONDecodeError Issue? python

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Can someone help me fix this, I don't know why I am getting this error.

I am trying to use a  python program someone made, I tried to mess around with it but I could not figure out the issue.

**Error:**

```
PS D:\Python> python .\quizlet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\quizlet.py", line 69, in <module>
    q = QuizletParser(website)
  File "D:\Python\quizlet.py", line 17, in QuizletParser
    data = json.loads(BeautifulSoup(session.get(link).content, features="lxml").find_all('script')[-6].string[44:-152])
  File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 14 (char 13)
```

I am trying to use the code I found here from a bit ago: https://github.com/daijro/python-quizlet

**Source:**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from box import Box
import box
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def FindFlashcard(flashcards: box.box_list.BoxList, match: str):
    similar = lambda a, b: SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    data = max(list(zip([similar(match, x.term) for x in flashcards], [x for x in range(len(flashcards))])))
    flashcard = flashcards[data[1]]
    flashcard.update({'similarity': data[0]})
    return flashcard

def QuizletParser(link: str):
    session = HTMLSession()
    data = json.loads(BeautifulSoup(session.get(link).content, features="lxml").find_all('script')[-6].string[44:-152])
    flashcards = []
    for i in list(data['termIdToTermsMap'].values()):
        i = {
            'index': i['rank'],
            'id': i['id'],
            'term': i['word'],
            'definition': i['definition'],
            'setId': i['setId'],
            'image': i['_imageUrl'],
            'termTts': 'https://quizlet.com'+i['_wordTtsUrl'],
            'termTtsSlow': 'https://quizlet.com'+i['_wordSlowTtsUrl'],
            'definitionTts': 'https://quizlet.com'+i['_definitionTtsUrl'],
            'definitionTtsSlow': 'https://quizlet.com'+i['_definitionSlowTtsUrl'],
            'lastModified': i['lastModified'],
        }
        flashcards.append(i)

    output = {
        'title': data['set']['title'],
        'flashcards': flashcards,
        'author': {
            'name': data['creator']['username'],
            'id': data['creator']['id'],
            'timestamp': data['creator']['timestamp'],
            'lastModified': data['creator']['lastModified'],
            'image': data['creator']['_imageUrl'],
            'timezone': data['creator']['timeZone'],
            'isAdmin': data['creator']['isAdmin'],
        },
        'id': data['set']['id'],
        'link': data['set']['_webUrl'],
        'thumbnail': data['set']['_thumbnailUrl'],

        'timestamp': data['set']['timestamp'],
        'lastModified': data['set']['lastModified'],
        'publishedTimestamp': data['set']['publishedTimestamp'],
        'authorsId': data['set']['creatorId'],
        'termLanguage': data['set']['wordLang'],
        'definitionLanguage': data['set']['defLang'],
        'description': data['set']['description'],
        'numTerms': data['set']['numTerms'],
        'hasImages': data['set']['hasImages'],
        'hasUploadedImage': data['hasUploadedImage'],
        'hasDiagrams': data['set']['hasDiagrams'],
        'hasImages': data['set']['hasImages'],

    }
    return Box(output)

website = 'https://quizlet.com/475389316/python-web-scraping-flash-cards/'
text = 'Two popular parsers'
q = QuizletParser(website)
flashcard = FindFlashcard(q.flashcards, match=text)  # finds the flashcard most similar to the input
print(flashcard.term + " " + flashcard.definition)  # calculates how similar the identified flashcard is to the input
```

Comment: The error means the string is not a json string. It points to the location of the character that broke the string.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a solution without looking at the data.

A few tips for debugging JSON errors:

1. Check the input data to the JSONDecoder. You might be adding a comma to the last key-value pair of the input dictionary (which is very common).
2. Check the data type. If your input data came from an external source check the data first.

I would suggest doing a print of this and pasting it here if possible.

```
input_data = BeautifulSoup(session.get(link).content, features="lxml").find_all('script')[-6].string[44:-152]
print(input_data)
```

Comment: I think the code is outdated I got this from that "fallBackUrl":"https:\/\/assets.quizlet.com\/a\/j\/dist\/i\/user_avatar\/avatar-fall-back.d5db6edb86bbcbc.png"

Comment: Okay. Then this is clearly not a valid input to the JSON decoder. 
1. It should start with a { and end with a } and all of that as a string "{...}" if you're using json.loads().

2. This data is not normalised: https:\/\/assets.quizlet.com\/a\/j\/dist\/i\/user_avatar\/avatar-fall-back.d5db6edb86bbcbc.png

3. This script was written for a specific 'URL' in mind I suppose so you should check the data of the URL you're fetching data from and should adjust the script accordingly.